# JS CSS line clamp reset (TextOverflowClamp.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using TextOverflowClamp.js to try and line clamp some text. It works while decreasing window width, but does not reset after increasing window width. Can someone help with resetting the line clamp after the clamp is triggered and window width becomes greater than set conditional size?

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/tbuchanan/pen/emMRmO)

All the code is in the Codepen, but my resize and load functions are here:

```
var winWidth;
$(window).resize(function () {
  winWidth = $(window).width();
  if (winWidth <= 991) {
    loadClamp();
  }
  else {
    // reset line clamp code here
  }
}).resize();

function loadClamp() {
  $(window).on('resize', function() {

    // TextOverflowClamp.js
    clamp(document.getElementById('js-toclamp1'), 1);

  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't seem to find a proper site for TextOverflowClamp.js. However, reading through the code itself, it seems passing `0` as the second parameter should remove the truncation *(It is unclear if this is intentional but it seems to work)*.  However, if there were any inner elements initially, those are lost and were not retained.  In the case of your example, it is just text, so it should be fine:

```
var winWidth;
$(window).resize(function () {
    winWidth = $(window).width();
    if (winWidth <= 991) {
        loadClamp(1);
    }
    else {
        // back to normal
        loadClamp(0);
   }
}).resize();

function loadClamp(lines) {
    clamp(document.getElementById('js-toclamp1'), lines);
}
```

Some additional notes on your code.  You were adding an additional `resize` handler every time you called `loadClamp` and there was really no reason for this.  I removed that.

Additionally, it is important that you place the TextOverflowClamp code before your own code.

http://jsfiddle.net/w9nkad0u/